# LyX: Graph (.emf) from Excel --- "Error loading file into memory" and "pdfTex Error"

Tags: graphics, lyx

I copy-paste graphs from Excel into LyX. I think LyX then converts it to .emf. (So far this is the only way I've found to ensure the graphs and images I copy from Microsoft Office are high quality in the final PDF output.)

It can often be buggy with errors, but after repeatedly hitting Ctrl-R, the PDF usually eventually outputs, as desired.

But recently I upgraded from Excel 2013 to Excel 2016, which seems to be when the current error started occurring.

I copy-paste a graph from Excel into LyX and I get the "Error loading file into memory" (shown below). And when I hit Ctrl-R, I get "pdfTex Error" and no PDF can be generated. Now repeatedly hitting Ctrl-R doesn't seem to be a fix.

[image]

Example of the specific EMF that's causing this error: [DJIAhisto.emf](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7VzKV1GxxEzWm1DcFgxb2RjYmM) (a JPEG screenshot of which is shown below). Excel file from which this graph was generated: [DJIA.xlsx](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7VzKV1GxxEzY1BPZE1xM25GOUk).

[image]

Comment: I opened the file with Libre Office and copy/pasted one of the graphics into LyX and it worked for me. It was pasted as .png though. LyX would not convert to .wmf (WMF is not a great choice because it is only common on Windows), but LyX does try to support all file types so if there is a WMF on the clipboard it will do its best. I'm not sure what to suggest since I can't reproduce your problem since I'm on Ubuntu. Hopefully someone else who uses Windows can figure out a solution. I'm guessing if you converted the wmf to e.g. png manually it would work.

Comment: @scottkosty: Thanks for your time trying. Yes indeed if I convert to e.g. PNG it works fine. But then it gets rasterized and the image becomes fairly poor. In contrast if I retain EMF it stays perfect

Comment: I see. What about eps and pdf? Do either of those work well?

Comment: May be a WMF ->  (Inkscape) -> PDF conversion could make the job without lossing quality.  Libreoffice Draw could be another possibility to make a PDF from a WMF.

Comment: @Fran: Thing is, the simple copy-from-Excel-and-paste method had been working well (and even now still usually works well except occasionally), so if possible I'd like to stick with the same method, because it's the easiest (rather than jumping through a few additional hoops). So I'm trying to figure out what (if any) the bug here is and how I can resolve it.

Comment: @KennyLJ (1) pdflatex, xlatex or lualatex only understand PNG, JPG or  PDF images (2) I am Linux user, but in Windows seem that LyX convert your WMF/EMF file to EPS and then to PDF with [MetafileToEPSConverter](https://wiki.lyx.org/Windows/MetafileToEPSConverter) (metafile2eps.exe) but (3) for some reason,  this conversion fail, but only  sometimes. So what?  Is not an obvious setup problem that you can solve, so you decide:  Sticked with metafile2eps.exe errors or search an alternative conversion. However, my long-term suggestion is  R or LaTeX graphs and avoid completely conversions.